# EvalPortalTicket returns error code 9 when parsing SAP Login Ticket in a .NET application

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, interop, netweaver

I'm trying to parse SAP Login Ticket (I'm getting ticket string from MYSAPSSO2 cookie) in a .NET application following the sample provided by SAP. Both `sapssoext.dll` and `sapsecu.dll` are placed in System32 folder but I'm getting an error which number is 9.

Here is the ticket string

```
AjExMDAgAA1wb3J0YWw6QVRJQUFNiAATYmFzaWNhdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbgEABkFUSUFBTQIAAzAwMAMAA1BNRAQADDIwMTMwMTA3MTAzNAUABAAAAAgKAAZBVElBQU3/AQUwggEBBgkqhkiG9w0BBwKggfMwgfACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATGB0DCBzQIBATAiMB0xDDAKBgNVBAMTA1BNRDENMAsGA1UECxMESjJFRQIBADAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMTMwMTA3MTAzNDE1WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQUYsJ!74Po!/9lrPqttjZXqcfBSTAwCQYHKoZIzjgEAwQvMC0CFD55F60sUc2gyG0gZpbdtLqJ6MBkAhUAiQ87p3inLvWchkphT5Lfl7PJ1mA
```

Here is the details logged in trace.txt file

```
---------------------------------------------------
trc file: "trace.txt", trc level: 1, release: "720"
---------------------------------------------------
[Thr 2172] Mon Jan 07 13:51:44 2013
[Thr 2172] Call function MySapLoadTicketKey 
[Thr 2172] Ticket key as new PSE loaded 
[Thr 2172] Cleanup of function, memory PSE created 
[Thr 2172] Leave function MySapLoadTicketKey with rc = 0.
[Thr 2172] Mon Jan 07 13:52:15 2013
[Thr 2172] MySapEvalLogonTicketEx was called.
[Thr 2172] Unconverted ticket is the following: >>>AjExMDAgAA1wb3J0YWw6QVRJQUFNiAATYmFzaWNhdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbgEABkFUSUFBTQIAAzAwMAMAA1BNRAQADDIwMTMwMTA3MTAzNAUABAAAAAgKAAZBVElBQU3/AQUwggEBBgkqhkiG9w0BBwKggfMwgfACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATGB0DCBzQIBATAiMB0xDDAKBgNVBAMTA1BNRDENMAsGA1UECxMESjJFRQIBADAJBgUrDgMCGgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMTMwMTA3MTAzNDE1WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQUYsJ!74Po!/9lrPqttjZXqcfBSTAwCQYHKoZIzjgEAwQvMC0CFD55F60sUc2gyG0gZpbdtLqJ6MBkAhUAiQ87p3inLvWchkphT5Lfl7PJ1mA=<<<
[Thr 2172] Initialized variables...
[Thr 2172] *** ERROR => Struct size 128 is not 128 [ssoxxext.c   459]
[Thr 2172] *** ERROR => MySapEvalLogonTicketEx returns 9. [ssoxxext.c   958]
[Thr 2172] End of function MySapEvalLogonTicketEx.
```

It seems it is internal error in "ssoxxext.c" ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP SSO EXT Lib (ssoextlib.dll) supports two ways of parsing login ticket

1. Instantiate an object from `SAPSSOEXT` class and use the `EvalPortalTicket` method to eval login ticket.
2. Use the static method `SAPSSOEXT.EvalSAPTicket` to eval login ticket

so based on ticket type that portal sends if it is SAP or Portal ticket, the appropriate method should be used.

For more info http://scn.sap.com/thread/1634545